# Is there an R function to export /convert excel file into text file?

Tags: r

I am trying to find a code for converting an excel file into text file.

This is the code for Excel workbook. I want to convert it into text file.

```
template <- loadWorkbook('V:/rcode/template.xlsx')

writeData(template,'sheet1',finaloutput, startRow =1,startCol = 3, colNames = FALSE)

workbook<- paste0("V:/rcode/", 'template', ".xlsx")

saveWorkbook(template, workbook, overwrite = TRUE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Read Excel file to data frame (tibble, technically) with `readxl::read_excel()`, write as plain text file.

```
library(tidyverse)   
library(readxl)

finaloutput <- read_excel("V:/rcode/template.xlsx", sheet=1, skip=0, range = cell_cols(c(3, NA)), col_names=FALSE)
```

read_xlsx would also work since you know the extension is .xlsx

```
write.table(finaloutput,"path",...)
```

Comment: @Anjaly did this help you? It would help my reputation on this site if you could please accept my answer as correct. I can try to revise it if it isn't helping you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.

```
library(readxl)
mydata <- read_excel("C:\\your_path\\Desktop\\File1.xlsx", 1)

write.csv(data, "C:\\your_path\\Desktop\\my_results.txt")
write.table(data, "C:\\your_path\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\my_results.txt")
```